# Sharepoint conditional auto approval workflow

Tags: workflow

I have a standard OOTB approval workflow which I have associated with a list.  I want auto approval of items in the list if the Rating field has been set to 1 or 2.  Only ratings of 3 or higher need to go through approval.

How can I do this?  In Sharepoint Designer I have edited a copy of the OOTB workflow to try and add the condition "If current item field equals value" But I cannot see the Rating field (or any fields) from the list item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible to Create Custom Rating column in List after that you can add the auto conditions in workflow

http://devendra-sharepoint.blogspot.in/2012/02/reusable-workflow-with-associate.html

Reffer this link